# how to get var type of array in controller action parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have create one array in view page like this

```
 var selected = [];
                $("#btn").click(function(){

                    var grid = $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid");

                    grid.tbody.find(".SelectedCB:checked").each(function(){
                        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                        var model = grid.dataItem(row);

                        selected.push(model);
                    });
                    console.log(selected);
 $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("actin", "testcontroller")',
             type: 'POST',
              data: { data: selected },
             dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {},
              error: function (result) {},
        });
```

and now to get array value in action method like this

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult actin(string[] data)
    {
    }
```

I have use string type but not call this action so which type of type may I use in controller?

Comment: Try with `data: JSON.stringify({ data: selected })`

Comment: now action method is called but string[] data value is null..!! please tell me more idea

Comment: because you are passing empty array do this way: ``var selected = new Array();``

Comment: no i have not pass empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialize data using `JSON.stringify()`. 
Try :

```
$.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("actin", "testcontroller")',
             type: 'POST',
              data: data: JSON.stringify({ data: selected }),
             dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {},
              error: function (result) {}
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
var selected = new Array();

selected.push("One"); // adding a item to array

$.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("actin", "testcontroller")',
             type: 'POST',
             data: { data: selected },
             dataType: "json",
             traditional: true,
            success: function (result) {},
              error: function (result) {},
        });
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult actin(List<string> data)
    {
    }
```

Comment: i have push some row value of my  grid.. and its also display in console.log but i want to only pass data to action method

Comment: try this chunk hope it helps

Comment: hello i use now List<string> data as per your suggestion now action called and count 1 but in data value is [object Object] so how to get proper value please help me

Comment: have you used all the code same as mine as i ran this code on my machine and is giving count 1 and object value is "one"